# Symfony2 and flat PHP CMS

Tags: symfony, content-management-system

I've got a CMS which I have been building over the last couple of years which is pretty big and does what the website needs perfectly. I'm about to re-build the frontend of the website using Symfony2 and was just looking for re-assurance that I could use my existing CMS which has no Symfony2 components and is pretty much flat PHP with a Symfony2 frontend? I will probably even put the CMS on a subdomain of the website so the website files will be completely separate but would obviously share the same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's no reason why you wouldn't be able to do this. You'd want to be careful of things such as result caching though as values may be updated in a completely separate system that wouldn't invalidate the cache.

Have you considered just using Silex instead if this is just for the frontend? It's much more lightweight so should provide better performance.

Comment: I too, would also recommend Silex for this kind of work. I've even refactored some of my plain vanilla PHP projects to use Silex